# nginx Sub directory with multiple location

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, configuration, webserver

I want to setup sub-directory in nginx. like

1. https://example.com/ (location /root/abc)
2. https://example.com/mysite (location /root/mysite)

my current nginx configuration is

```
upstream nodeproxy{
    server 127.0.0.1:3814;
}

upstream adminproxy{
    server 127.0.0.1:3817;
}

server {
    listen               443 ssl spdy;
    server_name example.com;
    location ~* \.(css|js|json|html|jpg|png|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        root /root/abc/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://nodeproxy;
    }
    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass         http://adminproxy;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_vary on;
}
```

I tried to put it like this but it doesn't work

```
upstream nodeproxy{
    server 127.0.0.1:3814;
}

upstream adminproxy{
    server 127.0.0.1:3817;
}

server {
    listen               443 ssl spdy;
    server_name example.com;
    location ~* \.(css|js|json|html|jpg|png|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        root /root/abc/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://nodeproxy;
    }
    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass         http://adminproxy;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_vary on;
}
server {
    listen               443 ssl spdy;
    server_name example.com/mysite;
    location ~* \.(css|js|json|html|jpg|png|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        root /root/mysite/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://nodeproxy;
    }
    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass         http://adminproxy;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_vary on;
}
```